# Why is MATPLOTLIB chart not closing after giving the command?

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts

In my program I have two charts. I have given the function

```
plt.close('all')
```

and

```
plt.close()
```

But the charts are not closing even after giving these two commands.
Here is my code:

```
#use this value for 'e', since my program is too big to paste here.I dont want to take much of your time
e=[[1,"food",456,"21/1"],[2,"health",654,"16/10"],[3,"transport",6500,"13/12"]]
monthlyincome=13000
def charts():
            def spentandsaved():
                plt.axis("equal")
                splist=[s,saved]
                lbl=['money spent','money saved']
                plt.pie(splist,labels=lbl)
                plt.show()
                plt.close('all')
            def categories():
                categories=[]
                amt=[]
                for i in range(len(e)):
                    categories.append(e[i][1])
                    amt.append(e[i][2])
                plt.barh(categories,amt)
                plt.ylabel('categories')
                plt.xlabel('amount')
                plt.show()
                plt.close('all')
            c='y'
            while True:
                print("1.View money spent vs money saved report(Press 1)")
                print("2.View Total Expense Report (Press 2)")
                print("3.View both reports")
                ch=int(input())
                if ch==1:
                    spentandsaved()
                elif ch==2:
                    categories()
                elif ch==3:
                    spentandsaved()
                    categories()
                else:
                    print("invalid choice!")
                c=input("Do you want to view the Report again(Y/N)")
                if c.lower()=='n':
                    break
        charts()
```

Actually only when i click close in the pie chart window the next line "Do you want to view the Report again(Y/N)" is getting printed. Why is this happening?

Please look into this problem
Thanks

Comment: What are your variables `s` and `e`? Reproducible code makes it easier to help identify your problem

Comment: I have made some changes please try to run this now.Thanks